# Problems with binding in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, text, bind

Asked this question earlier but I was unclear about what I was asking about. Have written a small program that basically opens up a text field and inserts three lines of data.

Have added one tag for each line through a while loop.

When I try to add bindings to the tags via a loop - nothing happens
the program doesn't respond at all. If I hardcode each keybinding, it works like a charm.

What am I doing wrong? Hope I didn't mess up the indentation whilst typing the code here

```
#!/usr/bin/en python
# *-* coding: utf-8 *-*

from tkinter import *

class guidelen:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("programmet")
        self.master.geometry("400x400")

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        self.tekstfelt = Text(self.master)
        self.tekstfelt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        setninger = ["første setningen","andre setningen", "tredje setningen"]
        start = 0
        posisjon = 1
        while start < len(setninger):
            pos = str(posisjon) + ".0"
            b = len(setninger[start])
            pos2 = str(posisjon) +"."+ str(b)
            setning = setninger[start] + "\n"
            self.tekstfelt.insert(pos, setning)
            self.tekstfelt.tag_add(setning, pos, pos2)
            #self.tekstfelt.tag_bind(setning, "<Button-1>", lambda start:self.utskrift2(start))
            posisjon += 1
            start += 1
        tagger = self.tekstfelt.tag_names()
        start = 1
        indeks = 0
        b = len(tagger)
        while start < b:
            self.tekstfelt.tag_bind(tagger[start], "<Button-1>", lambda indeks: self.utskrift2(indeks))
            indeks += 1
            start += 1

    def utskrift2(self, event):
        if event == 0:
            print("Taggen til første linjen")
        if event == 1:
            print("Taggen til andre linjen")
        if event == 2:
            print("Taggen til tredje linjen")
        if event == 3:
            print("Taggen til fjerde linjen")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = Tk()
    guidelen(start)
    start.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you looked at what `tagger[start]` is inside `while start < b` to verify it's what you think it is? Try comparing the tags you're binding to to the tags you're assigning to the text. Also, why aren't you adding the binding at the time you add the tags, rather than in a separate loop? It seems like that would reduce the chance that you're binding to the wrong tags.

Comment: Hello Bryan. tagger[start] are just the tag name list that was created in the first loop. I use it for giving the tags to the bind function. 
Made on purpose two loops - mostly for fault checking for myself. since I don't get the key bindings unless I hardcode them for each tag

Comment: I didn't ask _what_ it was, I asked if you have verified that the values are what you're assuming they are. You're clearly not adding bindings to the same tags you are adding to the text.

Comment: Ok. No I didn't verify what it was. But i used that data to hardcode the tags by hand and it worked like a charm.

I'm at a loss here to write the function correct